# Crystal Reports 8.5 / 9 - How do I remove a "default" value for a parameter?

Tags: crystal-reports

Can anyone enlighten me on how to find and remove a default parameter in Crystal Reports 8.5 and/or 9? I get all confused by visual code techniques like this where I can't just grep the codebase and find the string I need to remove. :D

Basically, it looks like the former developer saved the report with a couple parameter fields populated, and I'm not sure how to un-populate them.  So when I open this report for the first time and execute it, it just asks me for my database credentials - I never even see the:

- Use current parameter values
- Prompt for new parameter values

radio button selection the first time it is executed.

Any advice is appreciated.. thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In case anyone else happens upon this and needs a solution:

I have to uncheck

**File -> Options -> Reporting -> Save Data With Report.**

May this make your Crystal Reporting just a little less traumatic.

Comment: Yep, that'll get ya sometimes.